# Combine AND operator and limit length of characters in Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I have text `"Number 2169/B/PK/Pjk/2019"`, 
I want to match the following characters or strings `/Pjk/` that begins and ends with a forward slash and whose intervening characters are not forward slashes from that text.


I already use code 

`re.search(r"(\b/).*(/\b)", text)`

which are `\b/` for search the character start that with `/`, `/\b` for search the character that end with `/`, and `.*` as AND operator to combine those both conditions. 

But I still don't know how to add the condition to limit length of characters at least 5 characters `{5,}` from that code above. 

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Replace the `*` with `{5,}`

Comment: `Pjk` is not "at least 5 characters" though...

Comment: I have replaced the `*` with the `{5,}` but still doesn't work. I want to search for `/Pjk/` anyway.

Comment: @Wanderational That's because `Pjk` is not "at least 5 characters". It's only 3 characters. You are kind of contradicting yourself?

Comment: Are you including the two `/` in the count? You shouldn't.

Comment: You probably want to use `[^/]` instead of `.`. Otherwise it will match `B/PK/Pjk` since that's at least 5 characters.

Comment: How about `.split('/')[3]`?

Comment: Okay, let's say I want only `Pjk` characters, how do I combine two conditions in regex (start and end character) and length of characters?

Comment: `r"(\b/).{3}(/\b)"`. Or maybe simpler `r"/[^/]{3}/"`

Comment: if it may have more chars then use `,` - `r"/[^/]{3,}/"`

Comment: I think the confusion stems from your statement, "I want to search and extract the following characters `/Pjk/` from that text". The implication is that you wish to match that literal string of five characters (and not match, for example, `/Qrs/`). I suspect what you mean is that you wish to match every string of five or more characters that begins and ends with a forward slash and whose intervening characters are not forward slashes. If that's what you want @furas has suggested a regex that would suit your purpose.

Comment: @furas yes, that is exactly what I want. Thank you very much.

Comment: Wanderational, even though you may have the answer you were looking for, you have an obligation to SO members who read your question in future to make clear what you wish to do, so please clarify your question with an edit.

Comment: @CarySwoveland okay, roger that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get 3 chars between `/ /` you can do `r"(\b/).{3}(/\b)"`.

Simpler can be `r"/[^/]{3}/"` and it will not get `/` between `/ /`

For 3 or more chars you can add `,` (comma) `r"/[^/]{3,}/"`